# Integration testing with Events - Exceptions when running multiple tests at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, npgsql

I am using a shared database fixture for my tests, but when running multiple tests at the same time, I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

This is my code of my Fixture:

```
public class SharedDatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly object _lock = new object();
    private static bool _databaseInitialized;

    private const string postgresConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Database=IntegrationTests; Username=postgres;Password=password";

    public SharedDatabaseFixture()
    {
        Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(postgresConnectionString);

        Seed();

        Connection.Open();
    }

    public DbConnection Connection { get; }

    public AppDbContext CreateContext(DbTransaction transaction = null!)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
            .AddMediatR(typeof(IAggregateRoot).Assembly)
            .AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>))
            .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Connection))
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(serviceProvider);
        DomainEvents.Mediator = () => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMediator>();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        builder.UseNpgsql(Connection).UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

        var context = new AppDbContext(builder.Options);

        if (transaction != null)
        {
            context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
        }

        return context;
    }

    private void Seed()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_databaseInitialized)
            {
                using (var context = CreateContext())
                {
                    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    var appDbContextSeed = new AppDbContextSeed(context);
                    appDbContextSeed.SeedAsync().Wait();
                }

                _databaseInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() => Connection.Dispose();
}
```

The code I am testing uses events and those events do queries to the database. Therefore, I am registering some services and also a `DbContext`.

The problem is, when I run multiple tests at the same time, events are raised at the same time as well and because they are all using the same `DbContext`, it throws an exception when two handlers try to use the `DbContext` at the same time.

So, my question is: how can I instantiate a `DbContext` for each test (but using the same connection) or prevent it from using the `DbContext` at the same time?

---

An Example of one of my tests:

```
public class Project_Create : IClassFixture<SharedDatabaseFixture>
{
    public SharedDatabaseFixture Fixture { get; }
    public Project_Create(SharedDatabaseFixture fixture) => Fixture = fixture;

    [Fact]
    public void Creates_succesfully()
    {
        var project = new Project(SeedConstants.TEST_COMPANY_ID, "ABC", "Hallo123", "2018-123");

        Assert.Equal(SeedConstants.TEST_COMPANY_ID, project.CompanyId);
        Assert.Equal("ABC", project.Code);
        Assert.Equal("Hallo123", project.Description);
        Assert.Equal("2018-123", project.Number);
    }
}
```

Project.cs:

```
public class Project : BaseEntity<Guid, ProjectValidator, Project>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }

    public string Code {  get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string Number {  get; private set; }

    public Project(Guid companyId, string code, string description, string number)
    {
        CompanyId = companyId;
        Code = code;
        Description = description;
        Number = number;

        Validate(this);
        DomainEvents.Raise(new SetCompanyIdEvent(companyId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this project class raises an event. This event has a handler and looks like this:

```
public class CheckIfProjectIdExistsHandler : INotificationHandler<SetProjectIdEvent>
{
    private readonly IAsyncRepository<Project> _projectRepository;

    public CheckIfProjectIdExistsHandler(IAsyncRepository<Project> projectRepository)
    {
        _projectRepository = projectRepository;
    }

    public async Task Handle(SetProjectIdEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var project = await _projectRepository.GetByIdAsync(notification.ProjectId, cancellationToken);

        if (project == null)
        {
            throw new ProjectDoesNotExistsException($"The project with ID {notification.ProjectId} does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this illustrates what I am testing

Answer (score 1):

The answer is always simpler than you think.

When adding the `DbContext` in the Service Provider, I didn't specify the `ServiceLifetime`, so it is a singleton by default. Changing this to Transient solves the issue. Then the Connection should also be changed by the `connectionString`, so there are no multiple operations on the same connection.

So, this line:

```
.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Connection))
```

Should be change like so:

```
.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(postgresConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient)
```

Also, The registration of the repository should be as Transient and not Scoped.

Comment: That's simply wrong. The scope should remain `Scoped`. You need to specify a scope in the test instead. In an ASP.NET Core application each request specifies its own scope. There's no need to change the connection string either, unless you want to use a different test database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, if you would like to come up with a different solution, please feel free to do so. However, my solution is working flawlessly. But, if this is not the correct approach, I would love to learn.

Comment: I already explained that - create a scope explicitly for each test. This is a general problem [when a singleton service needs to call a scoped service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task-1). The answer shown in the docs is to use `IServiceProvide.CreateScope` to create a new scope and `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService< AppDbContext >();` to create an instance of a service that's disposed when the scope itself is disposed

Comment: `options.UseNpgsql(Connection)` is another problem. If this appears in the production code it's a serious bug too. Connections are managed by the DbContext so having an external long-lived connection *prevents* the DbContext from working properly. Connections are meant to be short-lived because any database locks and resources used by a connection remain active until it's closed. A DbContext only needs to open a connection when loading data or when saving changes. Connection pooling at the driver level means that opening/closing connections costs nothing.

Comment: Do you realize this is purely for testing?? This is not my Startup.cs, this is my Shared Database Fixture for my integration tests. This way they can share the same database and the database gets created and seeded only once. Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases

Comment: That's not what your code does though. It creates an entire DI infrastructure which goes out of scope once the context instance is created. Why is all this code used? Why not just create a new DbContext as the link you posted shows? That's the simple solution

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but as I explained, my code uses events and it needs the DI infrastructure because the required services otherwise would not be registered. If I do not use an internal serviceProvider I get a `System.NullReferenceException` I will add one Test + method I am testing to my question so you can better understand what I am exactly testing.